# No axes labels showing in NODF plot of R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, vegan

I am having problems revealing axis values in `R`. I am running a test on nestedness using the `vegan` package. The function is working, but my problem comes from the plotting. The ordering of the values are not explained. I chose to use the `nestednof(x, order = TRUE)` command to see what `nestednodf` would came up with. Using the `nodf` order, `R` found my sites to be nested, but I do not know which columns are which sites and which row are which species.

```
nn  <- nestednodf(PA4N)
plot(nn)
```

Order = TRUE

[image]

After not being able to figure out what my graph is showing I chose to use `order = TRUE`. I know which site is which and which species are which, except it is not as nested as the `nestednodf(x, order = TRUE)`.

```
nnf <- nestednodf(PA4N, order = FALSE)
plot(nnf)
```

Order = FALSE

[image]

Any advice on how R can show the names of the rows and columns?

Lastly, my rows are sites going west to east as columns. The presence and absence of snails following the sites they are in as rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the names flag to `TRUE`. See `?nestednodf` for details.

```
library(vegan)
data(sipoo)
plot(nestednodf(sipoo), names= TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still trying to understand nestedness, but the labels are so much more helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. Accept it as the answer if you are satisfied. `A consumer’s guide to nestedness analysis` is a decent review of nestedness methods.